# Moving objects in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a bug object that I want to move across the screen as soon as the game starts. The bug starts from the bottom left of the screen and is supposed to move to the top right and stop. What I have is the bug never really gets to the top right because the game screen(X and Y) size are not equal. How do I make the bug move to that position?

This is what I have.

```
public void create() {
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(); 
    bug = new Sprite(new Texture("EnemyBug.png"));
    bug.setSize(50, 85);
    bug.setPosition(0,0);
}
public void render() {
    xdeg++;
    ydeg++;
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    spriteBatch.begin();        
    bug.translate(xdeg, ydeg);
    bug.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you know your window width (W) and height (H). First find the W / H ratio:

```
float ratio = screenWidth / screenHeight;
```

Then update your bug position accordingly:

```
bug.translate(ratio, 1);
```

This will make the sprite move through the screen diagonal.

Comment: thanks, but your code didnt exactly work. I got it to work by doing this `bug.translate(ratio, (screenHeight/screenWidth)f);`

Comment: Don't understand why it didn't work, but I'm glad you got what you wanted.